# Components Library - Show Index

Tags: reactjs, components, web-component

I'm building a repository of reusable react components that would be shared between several internal projects.
I'd like to have an index file which will be used to show all the components in a single page, like a demo.

Is there a best practice or suggestion on how to do such an index while keeping it automatic/generic? (so that newly created components would simply be automatically added to the index webpage too)

Comment: There is [react storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook) which is a good tool to prototype and showcase components. Just automatically adding them will not work very good as most components would need some kind of sample data or props to provide. How should they be automatically generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) project as your UI development environment?

### Storybook

> Storybook is a UI development environment for your UI components. With it, you can visualize different states of your UI components and develop them interactively.
>
> Storybook runs outside of your app. So you can develop UI components in isolation without worrying about app specific dependencies and requirements.

[image: Preview of Storybook]

**Get started**

```
npm i -g @storybook/cli
cd my-react-app
getstorybook
```

Comment: Wasn't familiar with that. Thanks!